Find object data size in a .blend file
I am looking for an extension, or an addon, or some way to examine a .blend file and show the actual disk/memory size of each data block.
Is there a Python API that can inspect a data block and return the size of the data block?   I am quite willing to write some Python but I can't find the correct approach based on the Blender 4.2 API docs.

Hello. This is a great question, unfortunately I don't think it's accurately available with the python API, since the python objects are just proxies for underlying C/C++ objects. You would have to access the binary data in the blend file I think ?
